# Adding SSL support for AppEngine custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I have a custom domain setup for an AppEngine application. I have created the two required certificates using letsencrypt. I am aware that GAE requires a private key RSA file so I have done:

```
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem > privkey-rsa.pem
```

to create the `privkey-rsa.pem`. I am uploading that and the `fullchain.pem`file. These are accepted and I can see the correct domain under "SSL Certificates" in App Engine Settings.

I have set `secure: optional` for every route in my `app.yaml`

However, looking at the "Custom Domains" tab in "Settings", there is a column titled "SSL Support" which says None. I have removed and readded the custom domain with both the certificates present, and with them deleted.

But the "SSL Support" column remains at "None". And when trying to access my index.html page with https, Chrome produces 'Site cannot be reached'.

I seem to have no further options to try to get this working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine console **>** Settings **>** SSL Certificates **>** you'll see a list of certificates, click yours **>** mark the subdomain you want to serve this certificate through **>** Save

Comment: Yeah, took me some time to find it too the first time :)

Comment: Looks like with letsencrypt, that you have to put in both the `domainname.com` and `*.domainname.com` as I'm only seeing the option for the former, not `www.domainname.com`

Comment: Did you add the `www.domainname.com` to the App Engine app?

Comment: Yes, I did. letencrypt doesn't support wildcards, so I had to specify `domainname.com` and `www.domainname.com` - which both show in the certificate domain options. Yay!